# Not able to start a Selenium RemoteWebDriver instance in C# .NET4.5.2

Tags: c#, selenium

here is my setup: 
I've tried various driver/webdriver/grid versions, added capabilities just in case one mandatory was missing but had the same result.
Error also present if I delete the driver.exe file so this shouldn't be considered.

1. Start grid with bat file

start cmd /k java -jar grid3.14.jar -role hub -newSessionWaitTimeout 10

start cmd /k java -jar grid3.14.jar -role node  -hub http://192.168.1.229:4444/grid/register

2. Execute C# code bellow

   var options = new ChromeOptions();

   var uri = new Uri("http://192.168.1.229:4444/wd/hub");

   var driver = new RemoteWebDriver(uri, options);
3. Test fails with error:
   Result StackTrace:
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(Uri remoteAddress, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(Uri remoteAddress, DriverOptions options)
   at UnitTests.CodeRUnner.Run() in C:\UnitTests\UnitTests\Main.cs:line 26
   Result Message:

Test method UnitTests.Main.Run threw exception: 
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '3.10.0', revision: '176b4a9', time: '2018-03-02T19:11:12.151Z'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-F9MP198', ip: '192.168.1.229', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown (SessionNotCreated)

4. Node console log
   17:19:01.903 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$11] - Matched factory org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
5. Hub log
   17:19:01.895 INFO [RequestHandler.process] - Got a request to create a new session: Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {}}

17:19:01.896 INFO [TestSlot.getNewSession] - Trying to create a new session on test slot {server:CONFIG_UUID=2feea0b8-ace3-4bf5-8410-834034caba1c, seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=chrome, maxInstances=5, platformName=WIN10, platform=WIN10}